# Rectangle is divided into 14 identical smaller rectangles of width $x$. What is its perimeter in terms of $x$?

Tags: geometry, rectangles

Rectangle region ABCD show in below partitioned into 14 identical small rectangles, each of which has width x.

What is perimeter of ABCD in terms of x?

[image]

I have used rectangle perimeter formula but answer getting wrong . what is method to find answer in shortest way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If each small rectangle has width $x$, then we can see that the length of the small rectangles is 7 widths of the small rectangle, thus $7x$. Therefore, sides $AP$, $DQ$ and $BC$ have length $7x$. Finally, $AD$, $QC$, and $PB$ have length $7x$. Thus, we have six sides with length $7x$, so the perimeter has length $6\cdot 7x = 42x$.

Comment: Why $QC$ and $PB$ have lenght $7x$ ?

Comment: There are 7 rectangles along the side $QC$, each having length $x$.

Comment: Ok, in that case, why $DQ$ has lenght $7x$ ?

Comment: All of the small rectangles have the same dimensions, so $DQ$ has the same length as $PQ$.

Comment: You are saying that each rectangle has sides $x$ and $7x$ and that $ADQP$ is a square. Sorry, but I still dont understand your conclusion.

Comment: hmmmm...forget what I said, Im slow today and you are right.

Comment: How we can say length is 7x ? They said partitioned into 14 identical small rectangle

Comment: Can please explain bit more in details

Comment: Look at the $PQ$ line, its divided in seven parts(the horizontal lines) of size $x$. With this observation you know that $PQ$ has lenght $7x$. Note also that $PQ$, $BC$, $AP$ and $DQ$ has the same lenght.